# Catch url in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am getting url like **http://localhost/webpt/ipn/checkout/?token=EC-2YD51592ET0280122&PayerID=VNH3J2KQEK8AS** and want to catach in my controller. in my controller code

```
function checkout($token = array()) {
        echo"<pre>";
        print_r($token);
        echo"</pre>";
    }
```

but it show empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I just set `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';` in **config.php** & use 
`echo ($_GET['token']);` or `print_r($this->input->get()); // print all the get values` & it work fine thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

you can grab value of token by `$this->input->get('token');` since it is passed in url following a question mark.

Comment: I did print_r($this->input->get('token')); but now nothing is displaying.. :(

Answer (score 0):

if you mean that you want to catch the param `token`,
you have two options :

**format your url to be like** 
`http://localhost/webpt/ipn/checkout/nouman`

and you catch it in your controller like this :

```
function checkout($token) {
    echo $token;
}
```

**or use** `$this->input->get('token')`

```
function checkout() { // http://localhost/webpt/ipn/checkout/?token=8767&param2=333
 echo $this->input->get('token'); // echo the name param
 print_r($this->input->get()); // print all the get values
}
```

Comment: No the url is http://localhost/webpt/ipn/checkout/?token=EC-2YD51592ET0280122&PayerID=VNH3J2KQEK8AS

Comment: so you have to use the second option which is `$this->input->get()`

Comment: On second option it o/p:
Array
(
    [/ipn/checkout/] => 
)

Comment: & if i use echo ($_GET['token']); It o/p error: Undefined index: token

Comment: actually this token which Paypal returned me

Comment: is this for paypal , and what is the version of code igniter?, did you try it directly in the URL or you are trying from the paypalsandbox

Comment: Ok I just set $config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO'; in config.php & use echo ($_GET['token']); & it work fine thanks to all